# How to add data from a subcollection in Firestore to a List?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```dart
FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  CollectionReference _userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
Future getFriends() async {
    List<Map> info = [];
    await _firestore
        .collection('friends')
        .doc('lUb3VEzLQsqxxEhwO3nU')
        .collection('friends')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) async {
        print("hello " + element.id.toString());
        await _userRef.doc(element.id).get().then((value) {
          print("lalala" + value.data().toString());
          info.add(value.data());
        });
      });
    });
    print(info.toString());
  }
```

I am trying to build a Flutter application using Firestore.My firestore has two collections namely users and friends.Collection users contains documents with locations,names and Collection friends contains documents which each have a subcollection friends that store the Unique IDs of "users" who are friends. This is the output when I execute the above function
I/flutter ( 7773): hello eyHBWGrNoxSMe8cQUqWC
I/flutter ( 7773): []
I/flutter ( 7773): lalala{loc: Instance of 'GeoPoint', dname: hamza ansari}
**PROBLEM**: The data is not getting stored into the list 'info'. Any help with this would be appreciated :D
.Here is a photo of the friends collection.[image: Here is a photo of the friends collection]

And here is a photo of the users collection.[image]

Would really love it if someone could help me out here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the documents by snapshot.data.documents then you can get document Id like this

```
var doc= snapshot.data.documents;
var docId=doc[index].documentID
```

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('dishes')
              .doc(docId)
              .collection('ingredients')
              .snapshots(),
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that you are simply not returning anything in your `Future`.

try this

```
FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  CollectionReference _userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
Future getFriends() async {
    List<Map> info = [];
    await _firestore
        .collection('friends')
        .doc('lUb3VEzLQsqxxEhwO3nU')
        .collection('friends')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) async {
        print("hello " + element.id.toString());
        await _userRef.doc(element.id).get().then((value) {
          print("lalala" + value.data().toString());
          info.add(value.data());
        });
      });
    });
    return info ;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried doing this but this function just ends up returning an empty list to the caller. Is there any other possible solution?

Comment: do u have anydesk ?

Comment: no I dont, but I have uploaded the souce code to github and would gladly share it with you https://github.com/mithilchaudhary/mini_project_2

Comment: iam a bit lost in your code , if you provide me with anydesk or teamviewer

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the conversion of the subcollection to a list. Try the following:

```
FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  CollectionReference _userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
Future getFriends() async {
    List<Map> info = [];
    await _firestore
        .collection('friends')
        .doc('lUb3VEzLQsqxxEhwO3nU')
        .collection('friends')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) async {
        print("hello " + element.id.toString());
        await _userRef.doc(element.id).get().then((value) {
          print("lalala" + value.data().toString());
          info.add(Map(Map.fromMap(value.data())));
        });
      });
    });
    print(info.toString());
  }
```